# Is the Tall Tales (Play 1,000 rounds of Versus mode) trophy for Towerfall Ascension (PS4) broken?

Tags: achievements, ps4, towerfall-ascension

Is the Tall Tales trophy for Towerfall Ascension broken on PS4?

When checking my stats, I can see I have already played more than the 1,000 rounds of versus mode per the trophy description but it didn't unlock. I also see the statistic of the Tall Tales (Play 1,000 rounds of Versus mode) trophy are at 0% (meaning no player has unlocked it).

Could it be just the trophy description that is bad and the trophy is actually for completing 1,000 matches (not rounds)?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that right now the trophies are glitched:

> Glitched Trophies: The 1,000 round trophy, and presumably the 20,000 round trophies, are not unlocking. The developer is aware of the glitch and is working on a patch. At this point, it is unknown whether the trophy will unlock retroactively. I would recommend just playing the game normally and not worrying about not unlocking the trophy. If it gets patched and does not unlock retroactively, simply copy your save to a USB and start over. If you reach 20,000 rounds before the patch is released, I would recommend backing up your saved game to a USB flash drive just in case.

[Source of the info](http://www.playstationtrophies.org/game/towerfall-ascension/guide/)

Better be patient I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The *Tall Tales* trophy on PS4 was fixed with a patch on August 19th, 2014.

From the [Towerfall Devlog](http://towerfall.tumblr.com/post/95254470341/ps4-patch-released):

> Fixes:
>
> - **Fixed Tall Tales and Massive Mythology trophies never unlocking**
> - Fixed the new variant ’!’ on the variants menu not drawing with the correct transparency
> - Fixed facing direction flipping when another player bumps you while you’re ducking
> - Picking up your own crown no longer counts toward the Usurper Award
> - Picking up your own hat now only counts toward the Most Fashionable award if you were previously hatless